# Mongodb find()'s different format combine with skip() and limit()

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I found there are many ways to write a find() in MongoDB

like

```
find({'_id': id}, ['fieldsName'], (err, result) => ...
```

or

```
find({'_id': id}).select(['fieldsName']).exec()...
```

I want to implement skip() and limit() to my find(), I am using the first format,

> find({'_id': id}, ['fieldsName'], (err, result) => ...

do you guys know how to use skip and limit to this format of find?

because the resource I could only find will work on this format only or there is a better workaround.

```
find().skip().limit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using following format, it might work for you :

```
db.collection
  .find({'_id': id},{'fieldsName':1})
  .limit(limit)
  .skip(skip)
  .exec(function (err, result) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    return res.json(200, result);
  });
```

Comment: Hi, how would you return selective fields in your method? :)

Comment: You can add your fields which you want in project section like i did in edited solution. find({query},{project})

Comment: Thanks, it works, and I also add .select() to return selective fields. Thanks Happy coding